# Neukirch ANT I.9.4: Surjective morphism $G_\mathfrak{P} \to G (\kappa(\mathfrak{P})|\kappa(\mathfrak{p}))$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I think there is a gap in the proof of this proposition and am wondering how to fix it.

$L|K$ is a Galois field extension, $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{o}$ their rings of integers, $\mathfrak{P}$ is a prime over $\mathfrak{p}$ and $G_\mathfrak{P}$ is the subgroup of the Galois group fixing $\mathfrak{P}$. The automorphisms in $G_\mathfrak{P}$ will then descend to automorphisms of $\kappa(\mathfrak{P})=\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{P}$ over $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})=\mathcal{o}/\mathfrak{p}$. The proposition is then that this morphism is surjective (and that the field extension $\kappa(\mathfrak{P})|\kappa (\mathfrak{p})$ is normal, but I am OK with that part of the proof.)

The proof is as follows: pick a primitive element $\overline{\theta}$ for the maximal separable subextension of $\kappa(\mathfrak{P})|\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ (when $\mathcal{o}=\mathbb{Z}$, this is just the whole extension as every residue field $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ is perfect). Let $\theta$ be a lift of $\overline{\theta}$ to $\mathcal{O}$. Let $f$ and $\overline{g}$ be the minimal polynomials of $\theta$ and $\overline{\theta}$, then $\overline{g}$ divides $\overline{f}$. If $\overline{\sigma}\in G(\kappa(\mathfrak{P})|\kappa (\mathfrak{p}))$ then there is a zero $\theta'$ of $f$ which is equal to $\overline{\sigma} \overline{\theta}$ modulo $\mathfrak{P}$. Then letting $\sigma$ be an element of the Galois group sending $\theta$ to $\theta'$ does the trick.

The problem is I think we need to choose $\sigma$ more carefully to ensure that it fixes $\mathfrak{P}$. As a silly example showing not every $\sigma$ chosen above will work, choose an extension and a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ which splits completely (for example a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and a prime which splits). Then any element of $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ generates the trivial field extension, so our $\theta$ above is some element of $\mathcal{O}$. Then $\theta'=\theta$, and the $\sigma$ can be any element of the Galois group. In particular it can be chosen to send $\mathfrak{P}$ to some other prime over $\mathfrak{p}$, so not necessarily every $\sigma$ chosen by the proof fixes $\mathfrak{P}$.

The question is then how to close the gap: how do I know there is always a $\sigma$ which fixes $\mathfrak{P}$?

Answer (score 1):

You've actually missed out a key line of the proof (at least in my copy of Neukirch)! Using Neukirch's notation, let $Z_\mathfrak P$ be the subfield of $L$ of elements fixed by $G_\mathfrak P$ - i.e.
$$Z_\mathfrak P = \{\sigma x = x \,\;\;\forall \sigma\in G_\mathfrak P\}$$

Then since $G_\mathfrak P = \mathrm{Gal}(L/Z_\mathfrak P)$ (by Galois theory) and $|G_\mathfrak P| = ef$ (see prop 9.3), where $e$ and $f$ are the ramification index and residue degree of $\mathfrak P$ over $\mathfrak p$, it follows that the residue field of $L$ over $Z_\mathfrak P$ is exactly the same as the residue field of $L$ over $K$ with respect to $\mathfrak p$ - so $$\mathrm{Gal}(\kappa(\mathfrak P)/\kappa(\mathfrak p))=\mathrm{Gal}(\kappa(\mathfrak P)/\kappa(\mathfrak P\cap Z_\mathfrak p))$$

Hence, we can assume without loss of generality that our field $K$ is just $Z_\mathfrak P$ and that $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K) = G_\mathfrak P$, so you can be sure that $\sigma$ does indeed lie in $G_\mathfrak P$.